# Navigation controller with 3 tabs inside and no working title

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have 3 tabs and main navigation controller. I implements with code:

```
UIViewController *monitorController   = [[[MonitorController   alloc] initWithNibName:@"MonitorController"   bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *dashboardController = [[[DashboardController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DashboardController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *settingsController  = [[[SettingsController  alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsController"  bundle:nil] autorelease];

self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:monitorController, dashboardController, settingsController, nil];

self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.tabBarController] autorelease];

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I want to change navigation title when I select another tap, but no variant (see below) not working (there are no any title at navigation controller):

```
    self.title = DASHBOARD_TITLE; 

    self.navigationController.title = DASHBOARD_TITLE;
```

How I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UINavigationController` will display the title of the `UIViewController` it's currently displaying, that is why you are not able to set it directly.
You may try to change the `title` on your `UITabBarController`, but I'm not sure the navigation controller will update it's title after it first appeared on screen.

**But**, Do you really need that Architecture?
Usually the `UITabBarController` is the `root viewController` and if you need `UINavigationControllers` they are place `inside` the Tab that need to have navigation capability.
It was design to be use that way.

> Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar interface should never be installed as a child of another view controller.

Quoted from [UITabBarController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I misread your question, what you have to do is to implement `-tabBar:didSelectItem:`  from `UITabBarDelegate` protocol, and then change the title according to the pressed tab.

Or in the ViewWillAppear method of your controllers set the title, the way you were doing it

Comment: It's not resolve problem. self.title = @"title" will set title for navigation controller and tab controller.

Comment: First of all I need a title at navigation controller when app start …

Comment: So? it will inherit the title that is in monitor controller at first launch